# Protecting URLs in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I'm loading a URL into my app's UIWebView. Being a public URL, anyone could load it in any browser.

I'm wondering how I can best restrict access to this URL so that it's only viewable in my app's UIWebView and not any other browser?

Any ideas?

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in practice. You can authenticate the user using a credential (username and password for instance). You cannot effectively authenticate the application. In order to authenticate the application, you would have to give it a credential, which you would have to put into the application. If the credential is in the application, then anyone who has access to the application can pull it out.

You need to redesign your server to not be vulnerable to uncontrolled traffic. You cannot control the traffic that comes to you. You can authenticate the person who comes to you. If you focus on authenticating the person, then you can be successful.

Comment: Thanks, Rob - I think HTTP auth would be the the simplest solution. I was also wondering if it would be possible to use some sort of certificate to pass to the server with each request.

Comment: These are great if they're issued per-user or per-device. If you bake either into your app, then they'll just be copied and so have little value. If you can implement them very easily, sure, why not. But they won't give you much protection.

Comment: One other note: HTTP auth is worthless if done over HTTP. It is by default in plaintext (Base64, but that's the same thing). You need to use HTTPS if you want to use auth. You can then also verify that you're talking only to your server certificate (not just "some trusted certificate") which will give you a small amount of protection against proxies. This is challenging to achieve directly in UIWebView, though (you'd likely need to implement an NSURLProtocol; all likely more trouble than its worth). Explanation of NSURLProtocol: http://robnapier.net/blog/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol-588